# Simplify list.add of unknown amount of entries

Tags: c#

So I am currently working on a calculator.

One of the requirements is to store the history, which I currently do in a list.

While I have simplified alot of code I can't get my head around simplifying this

```
           if (amountNumbers == 2)
            {
                memory.Add(userNumbers[0].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[1].ToString() + " = " + calculation.ToString());
                userNumbers.Clear();
            }
            if (amountNumbers == 3)
            {
                memory.Add(userNumbers[0].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[1].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[2].ToString() + " = " + calculation.ToString());
                userNumbers.Clear();
            }
            if (amountNumbers == 4)
            {
                memory.Add(userNumbers[0].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[1].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[2].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[3].ToString() + " = " + calculation.ToString());
                userNumbers.Clear();
            }
            if (amountNumbers == 5)
            {
                memory.Add(userNumbers[0].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[1].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[2].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[3].ToString() + " " + op + " " + userNumbers[4].ToString() + " = " + calculation.ToString());
                userNumbers.Clear();
            }
```

Any idea how I simplify this and make the adding dynamic depending on how many values the user has chosen?
Preferably I want to store the whole string within one index since that is how the history is being displayed.

Comment: Does `userNumbers` have a length of exactly `amountNumbers`?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `Join` `userNumbers` values with `" " + op + " "` separator, then concat `calculation` at end:

```
string lastExpression = string.Join(" " + op + " ", userNumbers) + // Join values
                        " = " + calculation.ToString(); // Concat calculation result
memory.Add(lastExpression);
userNumbers.Clear();
```

There is no matter which amount of values in `userNumbers` - they all will be joined with `" " + op + " "` between each other.

Shorter version with string interpolation:

```
memory.Add($"{string.Join($" {op} ", userNumbers)} = {calculation}");
userNumbers.Clear();
```

**EDIT.**
This is very similar idea with **@JonasH**'s answer, just without converting `userNumbers` to a collection of strings. `Join` makes it implicitly at behind.

Comment: Thank you!
As a newbie there are lot of tricks that one is not aware of. This was perfect.
It also solved when I type out the calculation for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, loop over `userNumbers` and build your string, then add it to `memory` once you're done. Like so:

```cs
// Ensure that we don't get an 'IndexOutOfBoundsException'
// By clamping  'amountNumbers' to the length if 'userNumbers' if it's larger
if (amountNumbers > userNumbers.Length)
    amountNumbers = userNumbers.Length;

// You could use a normal 'string' and '... += ...' but 'StringBuilder' is more efficient
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < amountNumbers; i++)
    sb.Append($"{userNumbers[i].ToString()} ");

// Add the calculation, no space at the start required as the loop adds a trailing space
sb.Append($"= {calculation.ToString()}");

memory.Add(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.Take(amountNumbers)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0) to get **at most** `amountNumbers` of user numbers, . And [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) to combine strings with some separator between each:

```
var users = userNumbers.Take(amountNumbers).Select(s => s.ToString());
var str = string.Join(" " + op + " ", users);
memory.Add(str + " = " + calculation.ToString());
```

If you need some special handling for cases, like if  `amountNumbers< userNumbers.Count` or `amountNumbers == 1` you need to add that separately. If you know that `amountNumbers == userNumbers.Count`, then the `.Take(...)` is not needed.

Comment: Can you exaplain neccessity of using `Take` here? I think OP used so many `if`s of `amountNumbers == X` to avoid `IndexOutOfRangeException` when taking values from collection by index `userNumbers[X]`.